# Compare data from for specific column grouping and Update based on criteria

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with the following structure:

```
Employee  Project Task Accomplishment Score  Year 
John        A       1         5         60   2016     
John        A       1         6         40   2018
John        A       2         3         30   2016
Simon       B       2         0         30   2017
Simon       B       2         4         30   2019
David       C       1         3         20   2015
David       C       1         2         40   2016
David       C       3         0         25   2017
David       C       3         5         35   2017
```

I want to create a view with Oracle SQLout of the above table which looks like as follows:

```
Employee  Project Task Accomplishment Score  Year UpdateScore Comment
John        A       1         5         60   2016     60
John        A       1         6         40   2018     100     (=60+40)
John        A       2         3         30   2016     30
Simon       B       2         0         30   2017     30
Simon       B       2         4         40   2019     40      (no update because Accomplishement was 0)
David       C       1         3         20   2015     20
David       C       1         2         40   2016     60      (=20+40)
David       C       3         0         25   2017     25
David       C       3         5         35   2017     35      (no update because Accomplishement was 0)
```

The Grouping is: Employee-Project-Task.

The Rule of the UpdateScore column:

If for a specific Employee-Project-Task group Accomplishment column value is greater than 0 for the previous year, add the previous year's score to the latest year for the same Employee-Project-Task group.

For example: John-A-1 is a group which is different from John-A-2. So as we can see for John-A-1 the Accomplishment is 5 (which is greater than 0) in 2016, so we add the Score from 2016 with the score of 2018 for the John-A-1 and the updated score becomes 100.

For Simon-B-2, the accomplishment was 0, so there will be no update for 2019 for Simon-B-2.

Note: I don't need the Comment field, it is there just for more clarification.

Comment: you can most likely accomplish this with some analytic function.

Comment: Well structured question. It might be as simple as Score + CASE WHEN LAG(Accomplishment) OVER ( PARTITION BY Employee, Project, Task ORDER BY year)  <> 0 THEN LAG(Score) OVER ( PARTITION BY Employee, Project, Task ORDER BY year) , but what if there are more than two records with Accomplishment <> 0 for the grouping? Is the sum just taken for the latest of all N?

Comment: So - the interesting question is, if "accomplishment = 0" means that the score should not be counted, then why is the **update** score still the same as the "score" in years when the accomplishment value is 0? Shouldn't the **update** score, in those years, be 0? The query can be written either way (to get either output), I am asking only as a matter of logic. You may want to confirm with your "business" users who requested this view, to confirm one way or the other.

Comment: Also: What is the desired computation if for a combination of (employee, project, task) you have three years, with scores 20, 30 and 40, and the accomplishment values of 3, 0, 3? That is, the 0 is sandwiched between two greater-than-zero values? I assume the update_score for the first year is 20, and for the second it is 30 (not "updated"), but what is it for the **third** year in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Use analytic functions to determine if there was a score for the previous year, and if so, add it to the UpdatedScore.

```sql
select Employee, Project, Task, Accomplishment, Score, Year,
  case when lag(Year) over (partition by Employee, Project order by Year) = Year - 1
       then lag(Score) over (partition by Employee, Project order by Year)
       else 0
  end + Score as UpdatedScore
from EmployeeScore;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit strange -- you are counting the accomplishment of `0` in one year but not the next.  Okay.

Use analytic functions:

```
select t.*,
       (case when lag(accomplishment) over (partition by Employee, Project, Task order by year) > 0
             then lag(score) over (partition by Employee, Project, Task order by year)
             else 0
        end) + score as update_score
from t;
```

from t